Bar plot in Power BI to highlight the price point of a selected product on the bar(a dot or line on the bar)
How to create a bar plot in Power BI to show price range by categories and a selector of products to highlight the price point of a selected product on  the bar(a dot or line on the bar).
I have tried with Line with Stacked column chart. But failed to create a selector to select a single product to show as line or point.

You can do the following:

create a dimension table with a unique list of all your products;
use the product name from that table as a slicer (enforce single selection since as far as I understand you want to limit the lines on your chart to just one);
create a measure that would depending on a selected value from the products dimension table return a price of that product (not sure where your prices are stored);
use the measure as a function for a constant reference line on your chart


